# Can access `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` but not actual device IP address

Tags: networking, home-networking, localhost

I'm running a MacBook Pro connected to a TP-Link Archer C-7 router.

I can access my server running locally with both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. However, if I use the IP address of my device itself (as reported by Network Utility) say, `192.168.123.456` then it doesn't work.

I have a feeling it's something to do with the router setup but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: so lots of server software must bind to an IP interface, and by default they make you open it up for access aside from localhost by default. its a safety consideration. I'm not entirely positive on the netstat command bundled with MacOS, but for linux I'd run `netstat -ntlup | grep LISTEN` as root/sudo, and look for an entry for the port number in question. then I'd look at the local address. if its 0.0.0.0 or the LAN IP of the server, then it should allow connection. if its 127.x.y.z though, that means the server software needs to be configured to bind to the correct interface.

Comment: Why would you want or need to? 192...is your external address to the LAN. You will have another IP, to the internet. I don't know the actual mechanism, but I would posit it's like trying to pump water up the same pipe you want to draw from.

Comment: @mitt That is incorrect (except in obscure cases). On typical NAT IPv4 devices tje router has the IP bound to it and rewrites packets.

Comment: Sorry, that was written ambiguously. The router will have the IP to the internet*